# Backward vs The Other Way Around

Tags: word-difference

Which word/expression should I use, "backward" or "the other way around", to express something must be done or placed in an opposite way than it's being done or placed at the moment.

For example:

> - The phrase pen red is incorrect. You should place the words **the other way around/ backward**.
> - Your sign is **backwards/ the other way around**. Turn it.

Please I would ask you also to correct any minor mistake I have made and if it's necessary tell  me if there is a better way to say what I try to convey.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to words or letters that are out-of-order, the proofreading term for this is [**transpose**](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20transpose&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

A proofreader would use the following notation to show that the words need to be transposed:

[image]

You can learn more about this (and other similar proofreading notations) at websites like [this one](https://www.rit.edu/upub/proofreaders-marks-and-editing-guidelines), [this one](http://the-word-blog.com/2009/07/15/transposing-letters-and-words/), or [this one](http://www.csuchico.edu/pub/writing-style-guide/copy-editing.shtml).

Comment: Thanks. I have this doubt, Can backward and the other way around be used in same situations? Are they synonyms ?

Comment: @Liz - _transpose_ is a more precise term; _backwards_ is a more general term with more leeway in its usage. In the "He wrote with a pen red" example here, we could say, "Those last two words are backwards." Also, if the original was: _He wrote with a der nep_, we could say, "Those last two words are [spelled] backwards." However, we don't used _transposed_ for spelling unless there are two letters transposed, as in, "He rwote with a red pen" (where the 'r' and 'w' in _wrote_ have been transposed).

Answer (score 1):

You would say:

> The phrase "pen red" is incorrect. You should write the words the **other way around**.

or

> The phrase "pen red" is incorrect. You should **reverse* the words.

You can't use *backwards* because there is no forward/backward relationship or positioning.

Comment: Thanks. I have this doubt, Can backward and the other way around be used in same situations? Are they synonyms ?

Answer (score 1):

To describe your incorrect example

> The phrase *pen red* is incorrect.

You could say

> You should place the words *the other way around*.
>   The words are *backwards*, you should *reverse* them.

With your sign example

> Your sign is *backwards*. Turn it *around*.
>   Your sign is *the wrong way around*. Turn it *around*.

Though sometimes signs and lettering are intentionally inverted so they are correctly read when viewed in a mirror.

[image: here]

> It's **backwards**.
>   It should be the **other way around**.

Can be used interchangeably in most circumstances to describe orientation.

Comment: Thanks. I have this doubt, Can backward and the other way around be used in same situations? Are they synonyms ?